# CSS "unset" / "initial" in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Is there anything similar to

```
background-color: unset;
```

or

```
background-color: initial;
```

that is supported in Internet Explorer?

(before thinking in using javascript)

Comment: Related information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility It appears the only somewhat related option that IE supports is inherit.

Answer (score 32):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color), the initial value for background-color is `background-color: transparent;`. You could try to use that.

Comment: Good suggestion only glitch is that the correct name of the property is: transparent not color:transparant  :)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color), [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp), and [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-color) all list `background-color` as being fully supported in IE. (I guess disregarding the spec = supporting?) So if one doesn't think to specifically search for the values `unset` and `initial` and check *their* browser compatibility, a world of frustration awaits... until finding this Stack Overflow answer, at least. ;-p